# Database and Application on same physical server but on virtual machines

Tags: virtual-machines

Is it good practice to have the database of an application on the same physical server as the application but separated by a virtual machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems reasonable enough as long as there is enough resource - for the database server, be especially careful not to overcommit memory or CPU, and ensure that memory doesn't use the balloon driver.

Comment: Ignore memory and CPU ;) THe most likely overload candidate is IO - "the server has 2 dsics" instead of 20 ;)

Comment: Hi TomTom, how do you know?

Comment: Databases are disc IO intensive, but when virtualising we mitigate this by throwing memory at the problem.

Answer (score 1):

"Good Practice" - personally I don't like running production DBs in VMs but if you want to do that then actually running them on the same host would be great as your virtual networking between the two would be FAR quicker than any regular physical networking available.